# GWT vs bean validation inconsistency

Tags: java, validation, gwt, bean-validation

I'm trying to use validator.validateValue() method in GWT 2.7, and it does not seem to work correclty for the @Size annotation on a collection.

I'm trying to validate this POJO...:

```
public class Person {
  @Size(min = 3, message = "Name not long enough")
  private String mName;

  @Size(min = 3, message = "Not enough course subscriptions")
  private List<String> mCourses;

  public String getName() {
    return mName;
  }

  public void setName(String pName) {
    mName = pName;
  }    

  public void setCourses(final List<String> pCourses) {
    mCourses = pCourses;
  }

  public List<String> getCourses() {
    return mCourses;
  }
}
```

... using this validation method:

```
void validate() {

    final Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();

    final Person person = new Person();
    person.setName("Ed");//too short
    person.setCourses(Arrays.asList("Math", "Bio"));//not enough

    System.out.println("with validate object");

    final Set<ConstraintViolation<Person>> violations = validator.validate(person);

    for (ConstraintViolation<Person> violation : violations) {
      System.out.println(violation.getMessage());
    }

    System.out.println("with validateValue");

    final Set<ConstraintViolation<Person>> violationsName = validator.validateValue(Person.class, "mName", person.getName());

    for (ConstraintViolation<Person> violation : violationsName) {
      System.out.println(violation.getMessage());
    }

    final Set<ConstraintViolation<Person>> violationsCourses = validator.validateValue(Person.class, "mCourses", person.getCourses());

    for (ConstraintViolation<Person> violation : violationsCourses) {
      System.out.println(violation.getMessage());
    }
}
```

When running this code in plain Java I **correctly** get:

```
with validate object
Name not long enough
Not enough course subscriptions

with validateValue
Name not long enough
Not enough course subscriptions
```

But when running this code in GWT I **incorrectly** get:

```
with validate object
Name not long enough
Not enough course subscriptions

with validateValue
Name not long enough
```

It seems that the method Validator.validateValue(), in GWT 2.7,  does not validate correctly the @Size annotation applied to a Collection.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: +1 for asking a clear question. This seems weird because I have never had this problem with GWT 2.6. I did not try with GWT 2.7

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a String property.
When I reboot SDM, it works perfectly.

Badly, SDM must be rebooted after each change on validation.